# Is Server canonical for NPM?

Tags: node.js, npm, version, semantic-versioning

Which of these package version numbers is canonical for NPM?

- `2.0.0-pre1`
- `2.0.0-pre.1`

Comment: See https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver. What is Server; semver?

Answer (score 1):

NPM just uses the semver package, which follows https://semver.org/, so there isn't any "npm-flavored" semver.

According to semver, *both* of your examples are valid prerelease versions; the only requirement is that the version number is followed by a hyphen and a series of dot-separated alphanumeric identifiers.

That said, in my opinion, the second is more idiomatic, assuming that you are trying to convey the idea of prerelease version "pre #1". `2.0.0-beta.37`, makes it clear that this is beta #37, which comes after prelease beta #36 and before prelease beta #38; as opposed to `2.0.0-beta37`, which is ambiguous: `beta37` could mean beta #37, or it could be a codename for this particular prerelease, followed by `2.0.0-blue42` etc. etc.

Comment: In addition, mixed alpha numeric fields are compared lexically in ASCII sort order, such that a12 < a2, whereas a.12 > a.2.